# React-Native, Expo_router, Link: click a card in a screen and navigate to another screen and pass a value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, expo-router

I am using react-native and expo router for a simple project. I am using npm. In my project, I have a screen that has scrollable cards. Each card is a simple card with nothing but a text inside.

**I want to click the card and navigate to another screen. I also want to pass a value to that screen.**

For example: I have a card with the text "Card 1" inside it. When I click it, I want to navigate to another screen and see "Card 1" written in that screen. If I press Card 2, then I want to navigate to the same screen, BUT see "Card 2" written there instead. And so on.

I am trying to use **Link** from expo-router but the documentation is not working.

Here is my card component:

```
class CardSlider extends Component {
  state = {
    currentCard: 0,
  };

  handleCardChange = (index) => {
    this.setState({ currentCard: index });
  };

  render() {
    const { cards, style } = this.props;
    const { currentCard } = this.state;
    const colors = ["black", "white"]; // Define the available colors
    const numColors = colors.length;

    return (
      <View style={style}>
        <ScrollView
          horizontal={true}
          style={{ margin: 10 }}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
          {cards.map((card, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={index}
              style={[
                styles.card,
                { backgroundColor: colors[index % numColors] },
              ]}
              onPress={() => this.handleCardChange(index)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.text}>{card.text}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**To summarize:**

**1. Click the card**

**2. Pass a text value for that card**

**3. Navigate to another screen**

**4. See that text value on the screen**

Comment: So you are trying to have state available outside of the context of the component where the text is entered? Do you have a store and provider set up to handle the state for the card data?